# C# How can I store a user entered phrase into a string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am writing a program to scramble a user entered phrase. I have most of it coded, but I want to store the string of the user entered phrase into and array, with each word of the phrase stored as a separate element.
It seems like it would be a simple thing to do, but I just can't think of a way to do it. Can someone help me?

This is what it looks like so far:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool success = false;
        string phrase = "";
        string [] phraseArray;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Word Scrambler!\n\n");
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a phrase between 10 and 60 character long:\n\t");
            phrase = Console.ReadLine();
            if (phrase.Length - 1 <= 10 || phrase.Length - 1 >= 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must enter a phrase with a length between 10 and 60!");
                success = false;
            }
            phraseArray = new string[phrase.Length - 1];

            // String (phrase) into string [] phraseArray ?

            Console.WriteLine("See below for your scrambled phrase:");
            for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", phraseArray[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to scramble another word or the 'Esc' key to exit...");
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                success = false;
        } while (!success);`
```

Comment: After the first:  success = false;  You need to add a break to stop the rest of the code from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phraseArray  = phrase.Split();
```

OR If you need to remove empty strings

```
phraseArray  = phrase.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following...

```
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you want to save phrase just do this:

```
phrase+= inputString + ";";
```

After that you can split phrase into string array:

```
string[] yourStringArray = phrase.split(';');
```